# How to find conflicting thread in frozen UI

Tags: ios

I am having UI frozen/blocked due to semaphore_wait_trap in main thread.

When the UI is frozen, I pause using XCODE and the last two lines in stacktrace:

```
0x103f0ea30 <+809>:  callq  0x103f1554d               ; _dispatch_thread_semaphore_wait

dispatch_sync(someQueue, block);  // this is my code.
```

How can I find what is causing the block?

Any other suggestion to find out what is causing the block?

It always blocks on the same line/code.

Comment: In the Debug navigator (cmd-6), you should have a list of threads. One OTHER thread in there should be waiting for someQueue as well. I can't think off hand of a case where that wasn't the case. Usually the two threads are waiting for each other, (e.g. via dispatch_sync).

Comment: @Kalle...i think you are right

Answer (score 0):

In the Debug navigator (cmd-6), you should have a list of threads. One OTHER thread in there should be waiting for someQueue as well. I can't think off hand of a case where that wasn't the case. Usually the two threads are waiting for each other, (e.g. via dispatch_sync).

For example, you might have this:

```
dispatch_sync(mySerialQueue, ^{
    [self foo];
});
```

and

```
- (void)foo
{
    dispatch_sync(mySerialQueue, ^{
        ...
    });
}
```

The latter will be waiting for the former to finish forever, because the former is holding onto myQueue until it finishes the call to `-foo`.

(Note that `mySerialQueue` has to be created with the `DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL` for this to happen.)